# AndroidManifest.xml inside APK is not converted to binary

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt, aapt2

The apk that I build using `gradlew assembleVariant` builds OK, but for some reason the `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the apk is not in binary format. I can open it just fine in a text editor, which is unexpected. Other variants of my app don't have this issue and their manifests come out in binary format. I need it in binary format because that's the input that the next tool in the chain expects.
I am using Android gradle plugin 4.0.1. This wasn't an issue in 3.5.4.

Anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `android.useNewApkCreator=false` which helped me get past another issue: `Entry name 'AndroidManifest.xml' collided`.

This is not a good fix though, because the resulting `AndroidManifest.xml` is not the one you would want anyway. Find the conflicting `AndroidManifest.xml` and either exclude it or incorporate it in your app. Specifically mine came from a dependency that used CordovaLib.